# Query all records from a week in a month

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a Rails 5 app.
In this app I got Survey model. I am able to run queries (using scopes) to get all surveys from a specific month and all from a specific quarter but I want to get all from a specific week in a month too, how can I do that?

**These are my quarter and month scopes**

```
scope :period_quarter, -> (year, quarter) { where(created_at: Date.new(year.to_i, 3 * quarter.to_i - 2).all_quarter) }
scope :period_month, -> (year, month) { where(created_at: Date.new(year.to_i, month.to_i).all_month) }
```

How can I add a scope to get all surveys from a specific week in a month. I will provide year, month and week (1-5).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the same approach you've been using, only with [`all_week`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-all_week) and perhaps [`beginning_of_week`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-beginning_of_week) as needed to get the correct start date.

Comment: Like this? scope :period_week, -> (year, week) { where(created_at: Date.new(year.to_i, week.to_i).all_week) } I need to get a specific week of the selected month (1-5).

Answer (score 0):

To get a date in a specific week, you could use something like this:

```
def week(year, month, week_num)
    Date.new(year, month, 7 * week_num - 6)
end

week(2018, 8, 1).beginning_of_week # => Mon, 30 Jul 2018
week(2018, 8, 1).end_of_week       # => Sun, 05 Aug 2018
week(2018, 8, 1).all_week          # => Mon, 30 Jul 2018..Sun, 05 Aug 2018
```

To use this in a query, you could use it like this:

```
where(created_at: week(2018, 8, 1).all_week)
```

This will count the first week in a month as the week where the 1. is. However, if you want it to use the first full week in a month, you can remove the -6.